# Pros and cons of MIT Scheme and DrScheme for studying SICP

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp, mit-scheme

What are the pros and cons of using MIT Scheme versus using DrScheme, in the context of trying to go through [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) (presumably simultaneously to watching some / all the MIT 6.001 videos)?

Comment: You might dig more here for information on the topic:

http://groups.google.com/group/plt-scheme/search?group=plt-scheme&q=SICP&qt_g=Search+this+group

Comment: Note that PLT Scheme has support specifically for SICP students here:
http://www.neilvandyke.org/sicp-plt/

Comment: It's now called Racket - the IDE is DrRacket http://www.racket-lang.org/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I switched from MIT Scheme to DrScheme specifically because I couldn't get a version of MIT that runs on 64-bit Windows.  I run DrScheme with the Language "Module" selected to do the SICP exercises.

Comment: Thanks.  Have you encountered any problem doing that?

Comment: @JDelage: No, not yet.  I'm only about halfway through the exercises in chapter 1 of SICP, but I've also run some example code from here on SO and from the solutions on Programming Praxis (http://programmingpraxis.com/) with the same settings with no problems.

Comment: Bill - That programmingpraxis site seems awesome, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

DrRacket got me up and running in Scheme with little to no thought. I didn't really need to learn anything new in terms of the tools needed to work the language. Furthermore, you get access to tons of packages for the PLT/Racket environment. I installed Vi mode (http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=vi.plt&owner=kazzmir) for DrRacket which made solving the SICP exercises a little less painless.

Here's a guide that spells out setting up DrRacket for SICP. It's really easy.
http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp/

Answer (score 4):

*This answer was originally posted in the question body.*

Please feel free to edit below:

#### MIT Scheme

Pros:

- Specifically built for SICP and MIT 6.001.

Cons:

- (none yet)

#### DrScheme

Pros:

- Wider-spread usage, more active community.

Cons:

- (none yet)